# Call json in localhost is normal, but in server error display "unexpected token in json at position 0"

Tags: javascript, json, server, localhost

When I call json in localhost is normal, but in server (intranet) error display "unexpected token in json at position 0". Why? and how can I fixed it?

Comment: There is an error parsing your JSON

Comment: Could it be that the JSON your trying to parse is already converted to an Object? I.e. if your fetching the JSON with jQuery.ajax, it automatically parses the JSON to an Object. Can you post some code?